# get the value of an input on changed value in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have the following action in my controller:

```
actions:{
    doSomething:function(a){console.log("do something",a)}
}
```

In my template I have:

```
{{input value=50 name=variableName action="doSomething" on="input"}}
```

However the function never fires when I change the input value, ie by typing or deleting the placeholder value of 50.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the changed value of the input box?

Note: I use `on="input"` because I want to do something when the input value changes, but let me know if I should be using a different event. Using `key-press` results in the method firing, but the input value printed to the console is the 'before-any-changes' input value. I need the input value after someone has typed into the field. I tried using `key-up` but the method doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an observer on `variableName` it will trigger the function whenever it changes,

```
onInput: function() {
  // do something
}.observes('variableName')
```

see the guide for more details http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/observers/

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I find it wierd they have an 'action' attribute and an event listener, but I still have to use the observes method